# Ios Swift 2 passing second argument for selector

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying add a second parameter while calling selector, can anyone tell me how to do it exactly

I Tried :

```
let BtnVar = UIButton(title: "TrlTxt",
                       style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                       target: self,
                       action: #selector(self.NavRitBtnKlk(_:, Nam2Var)))

func NavLitBtnKlk(sender: UIButton, Nam1PsgVar: AnyObject)
{
    /* CodTdo */
    print("Clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector should be

```
#selector(self.NavRitBtnKlk(_:Nam1PsgVar:))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans

Comment: @SujayUN Click mark as answer, and then you'll be able to vote up.